# type assertion failed. type == CV_8UC1 || stype == CV_16SC1 || stype == CV_32SC1 || stype == CV_32FC1 in function

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following code in opencv 4.3.0:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("disp.png")
persp_trans = np.random.rand(4,4)
print(cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(img, persp_trans))
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "disp_3d.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(img, persp_trans))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp:2990: error: (-215:Assertion failed) stype == CV_8UC1 || stype == CV_16SC1 || stype == CV_32SC1 || stype == CV_32FC1 in function 'reprojectImageTo3D'
```

Why is that and how to fix this?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Please include all symbol definitions (you're missing at least two `import` statements) and a public-domain input file.  Also trace the types of your arguments; compare to the documented requirements.

Comment: Does the code work for you?

Comment: The assertion states that the source type must be a single-channel image, so presumably you're passing a 3-channel image to it instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this answer:

[OpenCV: Error when using function cvGoodFeaturesToTrack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680816/opencv-error-when-using-function-cvgoodfeaturestotrack)

You may need to grayscale your image first using :

```
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```